# Difference between make-kpkg and make deb-pkg

Tags: compiling

I have build the kernel image by make-kpkg and  make deb-pkg in 13.04 ubuntu and noticed that image size is very big in case of deb-pkg build. 
deb-pkg build size is 13 times bigger than make-kpkg .
Can anyone please share why the difference is there ?

Regards
Titu

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well. The answer I found is documented here: http://users.wowway.com/~zlinuxman/Kernel.htm#Configure, last two paragraphs of the section. Basically it comes down to debug info being included in your kernel (CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=Y) and also in the modules (not using make variable INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1). My builds were ~400MB before, and ~40MB after.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Tim Indeed! Now the link is broken :(